# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet` 'Where' not found

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

this solution has 4 layers.

in the BLL there is Validation Method check the user input (Server Validation )
the Error happend here:

BLL.server

```
Entities dbo = new Entities { };
var query = from c in dbo.database1 where c.id == id select c.Name;
```

I reference

- using System.Linq;
- using System.Data.Linq;
- using System.Data.Entity;

and other lower Project,

if there a good approach to make it right HINT me please.

Answer (score 2):

In your query you select from `context.db.Name`, whereas you should select from `context.db`, otherwise `select c.Name` would mean `context.db.Name.Name`

```
Entities dbo = new Entities();
var query = from c in dbo.database1 where c.id == id select c.Name;
```

Comment: What type of `dbo.database1` do you have? you also should use constructor method followed by`()`